# How to populate an android spinner with data coming from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I already have populated my android spinner with data coming from mysql. But instead of getting 1 data per type i get everything. Example i have 2 basketball in my database, the android spinner shows 2 basketball instead of 1

PHP

```
$sql = "select s_name from sport order by s_name asc;"; 
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$tmp[] = $row;
 }


echo json_encode ($tmp);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the response i get. Instead of getting only 1 value. I get everything from s_name in my android spinner

```
[{"0":"Basketball","s_name":"Basketball"},    {"0":"Basketball","s_name":"Basketball"}, 
    {"0":"Basketball","s_name":"Basketball"},
```

Comment: In your example, if you have 2 basketball in your database, why would the spinner show 1?

Comment: When i add matches sir. Example two match are playing basketball. So there's two basketball inserted. How do i get only 1 for my spinner?

Comment: Works thank you very much!

Comment: yes sir. post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `group by` in your query :

```
$sql = "select s_name from sport GROUP BY s_name order by s_name asc;";
```